# Cannot convert charset 1253 from webscraping using python beautifulsoup to utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I trying to web scrape a webpage with html charset part

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1253">
```

The whole html instead of Greek Characters shows the following

I get characters like

```
'¢ìåóá  ÄéáèÝóéìï'
'20,65\xa0\x80'
```

I try to convert it like

```
price.text.strip().decode('cp1253').encode('utf8')

soup = BeautifulSoup(Myhtml, 'html.parser').decode('cp1251').encode('utf8')
```

but again nothing only invalid characters

Comment: Can we have the url?

Comment: it is likely that the text string containing the content of the web page is already read in a wrong encoding. How do you get the contents of the web page?

Comment: @Qharr the main url is https://www.oktabit.gr in chrome is shown normal, Is a login site

Comment: @Clemens  soup = BeautifulSoup(Myhtml, 'html.parser'), I using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: I was just wondering where `Myhtml` comes from. Btw; `print( b'\xa0\x80'.decode('cp1253') )` looks ok when I test it. you maybe do not need the `encode('utf8')` step with python3.

Comment: So I can do price.text.strip().decode('cp1253') ?

Comment: @Qharr Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

After many tests I end up with the following

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    r.encoding = 'cp1253'
    Myhtml = r.text
```